# Why dompdf does not recognize the "target" attribute in the HTML code?

Tags: php, html, dompdf

Why dompdf doesn't recognize the `target="_blank`" attribute ? What can I do to make this work ? I also tried with `target = "_tab"`. This is my code :

```
  <?php
    error_reporting(0); ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1); set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "dompdf"); require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $fk_marca = $_GET['id'];$fk_familia = $_GET['m'];$session = $_GET['session'];
    $img_url = $_GET['img_url'];$titleCategoria = $_GET['title'];$nr_of_lines = $_GET['nr_of_lines'];
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $img  = "background-image:url('http://acros.netlogiq.info/dompdf/img/pic.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;";
    $img2 = "background-image:url('http://acros.netlogiq.info/dompdf/img/pic2.png');";
    $img3 = "background-image:url('http://acros.netlogiq.info/dompdf/img/Dungi6.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;";
    $header = '<div id="imageHeader" style="'.$img3.';width:1000px;">
                <div style="width:400px;">
                    <p style="margin-left:80px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:30px;font-family: \'Trebuchet MS\', \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', Tahoma, sans-serif;">MANUAL T&Eacute;CNICO</p>
                    <p style="margin-left:80px;padding-top:-8px;font-weight:bold;font-family: \'Trebuchet MS\', \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', Tahoma, sans-serif;">FAMILIA:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'.$titleCategoria.'</p>
                </div>
                    <img  style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:-110px;" src ="http://acros.netlogiq.info/'.$img_url.'">
                    <div style="margin-left:725px;width:15px;margin-top:-20px;background-color:white;font-weight:bold;"><span class="pagenum">&nbsp;</span></div>
            </div></div><br><br><br><br>';
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'netlogiq_attin', 'attin');
    $db = mysql_select_db("netlogiq_acros");
    if ($fk_familia == 0 ){
        $and = "fk_familia ='$fk_marca' ";
    }else{
        $and = "fk_marca = '$fk_familia' and fk_familia = '$fk_marca'";
    }
    $query = "select articulo,descripcion,imagen,link,precio,codigo from prod_detalle where ".$and." ";
    $select = mysql_query($query);
    $count_query = mysql_num_rows($select);
    $count = 1;
    $html = '<html>
        <style>
           <style>
            @page { margin: 180px 50px; }
            #imageHeader { position: fixed; height: 120px; margin-left:-50px;margin-top:-50px;}    
            .pagenum:after { content: counter(page); }
        </style>'.$header.'<br><br> ';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
        $url = $row['imagen'];
        $title = $row['articulo'];
        $file = 'txt/textarea.txt';
        $desc =  $row['descripcion'];
        $link =  $row['link'];
        $codigo = $row['codigo'];
        if (empty($session))
            $price = " ";
        else
        $price = "<div style='margin-left:420px;'><span style='color:red;font-size:22px;'><b>".$row['precio']."&euro;</b></span></div>";
        if (empty($link)){
            $link = '&nbsp;';
        }else{
            $link = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  target="_blank" href ="'.$link.'">Link Fabricante</a>';
        }
        file_put_contents($file, $desc);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            $text ="";$i = 1;
            while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
                if ($i <= 9 ){
                    if ($buffer !=""){
                        $text = $text.$buffer;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        $wh ="";
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://acros.netlogiq.info/fotos/".$url); // get image info
        $ratio = $width/$height;
        if( $ratio > 2) {
            $width = 170;
            $height = 200/$ratio;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:-30px;margin-top:40px;";
        }elseif($ratio > 1.4 && $ratio < 2){
            $width = 170;
            $height = 160/$ratio;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:-30px;margin-top:30px;";
        }elseif($ratio <= 1 && $ratio > 1.099){
            $width = 160;
            $height = 144/$ratio;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:-24px;margin-top:10px;";
        }elseif($ratio >= 1.099 && $ratio <= 1.4){
            $width = 170;
            $height = 160/$ratio;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:-30px;margin-top:10px;";
        }elseif ($ratio < 1  && $ratio > 0.72) {
            $width = 80;
            $height = 80;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:16px;margin-top:40px;";
        }elseif ($ratio <= 0.72) {
            $width = 70;
            $height = 80;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:16px;margin-top:40px;";
        }else{
            $width = 70;
            $height = 80;
            $wh = "width:".$width."px;height:".$height."px;margin-left:16px;margin-top:40px;";
        }
        if ($count != 1){
            if (($count - 1) % 4 == 0){
                $marginTop = "padding-top:-76px;";
            }else{
                $marginTop ="padding-top:0px;";
            }
        }
        $html .= ' <div style="'.$marginTop.'">
            <div style="float:left;margin-left:-50px;padding-left:90px;height:200px;'.$img.'">
                <img src = "http://acros.netlogiq.info/fotos/'.$url.'" style="'.$wh.'">
            </div>';
        $html.= '<div style="padding-left:300px;margin-left:-35px;width:500px;height:160px;padding-top:10px;'.$img2.'">
                <span style="color:#574595;font-family: \'Arial Rounded MT Bold\', \'Helvetica Rounded\', Arial, sans-serif;"><b style="">'.$codigo.' '.$title.' </b></span><br>
                '.$price.'
                <span style="font-size:12px;font-family: \'Trebuchet MS\', \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', Tahoma, sans-serif;">'.$text.'</span>
                </div><div style="clear:both"></div><br></div><div style="clear:both"></div>'.$link.'';
                    if ($count % 4 == 0){
                        if($count !=  $count_query){
                            $html.='<p style="page-break-before: always;"></p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>';
                        }else{
                            $html.='';
                        }
                    }elseif(($count % 4 != 0) && ($count ==  $count_query)){
                            $html.=' ';
                    }
        $count ++;
    }
    $html .='</html>';
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents("pdf_generated/file.pdf", $output);
    header("Location: http://acros.netlogiq.info/pdf_generated/file.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: `target` is not an element, it is a _attribute_ of the a tag.

Comment: Please post the final html anchor, not this incomplete fragment.

Comment: Target is an HTML attribute, it has NOTHING to do with PDF and will never be taken into account in PDF files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dompdf uses the URI action to provide linking support ([see section 7.5.3 of the PDF 1.3 spec](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/PDF_1.3/PDF%20Reference%201.3.pdf)). This action does not support supplying a target window for the link.

It's easy to see how viewing a PDF in the browser that you might expect to have this functionality. The PDF document is just one more tab/window in the browser. However, if you think about PDF documents in isolation the lack of this functionality is understandable. A PDF document opened directly on your computer would open in an app, and clicking any URI links would load via an external app (the web browser). So the PDF spec does not have any knowledge of windows/tabs, especially the version of the spec currently targeted by dompdf.